# How can I build master against only stable Rust on Travis CI?

Tags: rust, travis-ci

I currently build a Rust app against both `stable` and `beta`. Branch debug builds are reasonably quick – 5 minutes – but release builds can reach 45 minutes. I currently have a paid Travis plan with two simultaneous jobs. Building against both stable and beta means that no other CI jobs execute for 45 minutes.

I only care about the build artifacts from the `stable` job. How can I exclude `beta` from master and tagged builds?

My .travis.yml:

```
sudo: false
language: rust
rust:
- stable
- beta

matrix:
  fast_finish: true
  allow_failures:
    rust:
    - beta

cache:
  cargo: true
  timeout: 600

script:
- make pkginfo
- make test
```

I think I need to make modifications to the `matrix` but the [Build Matrix](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/#Build-Matrix) docs aren't really clear about how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can move the `rust` toolchain definitions into the build matrix and [specify which branches to build](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/#building-specific-branches) independently. With the help of a branch blacklist and a regular expression for capturing tagged commits (assuming the format `v#.#.#`), we get the following:

```
sudo: false
language: rust

matrix:
  fast_finish: true
  include:
  - rust: stable
  - rust: beta
    branches:
    except:
    - master
    - /^v\d+\.\d+(\.\d+)?(-\S*)?$/
  allow_failures:
    rust:
    - beta

cache:
  cargo: true
  timeout: 600

script:
- make pkginfo
- make test
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work: the beta job still executed. I did have to remove the `v` from the regex because our tags do not contain it, but it should be otherwise the same… https://gist.github.com/colindean/c0aeee4150e7d56747e2c6ca05493835